# Fill DataGridView from a DataSet Created in designer

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a DataSet Dynamicly  which contains one table :
[Here is my DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVHZB.png)

I want to fill it with values from my view Demande in my Database. I tried this code Here :

```
 string cnstr = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Gestion Commercial Officielle;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
        cn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter daAuthors = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Demande", cn);
        DataSet1 d = new DataSet1(); 
        daAuthors.FillSchema(d, SchemaType.Source, "Demande");
        daAuthors.Fill(d, "Demande");
        grid.DataSource = d;
        grid.DataMember = "DataTable1";
```

It just returns an empty DataGridView like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfjrT.png) .

Please could someone help please to figure out where i missed up ? 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Did you set the columns on the DataGridView yourself? If not then it appears to be working but you have no data coming from your database. DataGridView will create the columns for you based on the bound data unless you specify in code grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

Comment: @HandbagCrab But plz execuse me Sir  I dont get why there is no data in the datagridview ?

Comment: Maybe the column names in DataGridView comes from the Datatable1 created in my dataSet ..I think my DataTable1 is still empty.

Comment: Ok, so we know that you have an empty data table in your dataset as your DataGridView has columns related to the DataTable. Now we need to figure out why "select * from Demande" is not returning any data. First question is, does your database actually contain some data? If you connect to your db via management studio (or VS) and run the query will it return anything? If it does contain data and your query returns records then you can run the SSMS profiler to see if data is being transferred and also check the table in your data set to see if it has any records.

Comment: I've run this locally, with my own db. I don't know what "DataSet1" is in your code so I used a normal DataSet. I got an error using "DataTable1" so I used the name of the table I was pulling data from and it worked. It pulled data filled the data and displayed the data. I'd suggest that your issue lies with DataSet1 IF you have found you've got data in your database.

Comment: Change DataSet1 d = new DataSet1(); to DataSet d = new DataSet(); and then change grid.DataMember = "DataTable1"; to grid.DataMember = "Demande";

Comment: First of all thank you for ur help ! secondly , I tried what you just suggested to me  and i find out : 1-my database table has records  -2-there is no data transfered to my dataSet 3-and my dataSet is empty ....I tried the same solution without using the designer to create a dataSet and it worked for me .. Bu Sir what I need is to fill my dataSet in my Desirner because I want to use it As a source to create a report .

Comment: DataSet1 is a DataSet which I created in Desiner   : [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVHZB.png)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any further. I don't ever use the designer to create data sets. I've only ever done it via code.

Comment: Thank You Sir ! I very appreciate your Time and your efforts Thank you ! :)

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm just sorry I can't be of more assistance.

Comment: I understand I do appreciate you taking time to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution , so here it is :

1- create dataSet in designer called report.xsd

2- create inside the dataset designer a table name it for exemple : demande

3-create a class where u fill your dataset . ***Here is the code :***

```
 class report
{


    public void reportDemande (int n)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        reports.DemandeDataTable d = new reports.DemandeDataTable();
         foreach(var i in db.tbl_detail_demande.Where(c=>c.id_demande==n) )
        {
            DataRow r = d.NewRow();
            r[0] = i.code_article.ToString();
            r[1] = i.tbl_article.designiation;
            r[2] = i.quantite_demande;
            r[3] = i.tbl_demande_achat.observation;

            d.Rows.Add(r);

        }

    }
}
```

Hope it will help someone else in the futur .